# Git leaves files unstaged

Tags: git

I have a weird problem. 
No matter what I do - Git leaves several files in my repo unstaged. 
I tried committing to a separate branch, stashing them - does not help. 
So far this happened to only one repository. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Does `git status` say anything abnormal?

Comment: @gmdev it does not

Comment: Do they actually show up as changed when you run `git status`, or as "untracked"?

Comment: Is this just a local repo or is there a remote as well?

Answer (score 0):

Cloned this repository to new location and found many more files changed. 
Turns out I had .gitattributes file. After I deleted it - the changed files went away

Comment: Normally, .gitattributes is there for a reason. Can you explain why it is a good idea in your case to delete the file?